# Separate Powershell output from return value when run from Python

Tags: python, powershell

I have this example.ps1 script:

```
function myfunc
{
    Write-Host "Write message"
    return 1234
}

$result = myfunc
Write-Host "result: $result"
```

When run in Powershell, it returns the return value as variable `$result`:

```
PS C:\Example> .\example.ps1
Write message
result: 1234
```

When run in Powershell subprocess from Python script:

```
import subprocess
def run(cmd):
    completed = subprocess.run(["powershell", "-Command", cmd], capture_output=True)
    return completed

if __name__ == '__main__':
    completed = run(". .\example.ps1")
    result = completed.stdout
    print(result)
```

It returns:

```
C:\Example>python example.py
b'Write message\nresult: 1234\n'
```

How can I capture the return value as variable `result` in Python (like Powershell does)?

Reason for asking is that I want logging of the Powershell scripts (Write-Host, Write-Verbose, etc.) to standard output and the return value in a variable for further processing in Python.

Comment: Can you please provide the expected output from the Python script?

Comment: Expected output in Python is merely the return value, i.e. `1234`